# How does a merge preserve a block in an Lucene index, when the index does not currently record which documents were added as a block

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to figure out what a block in Lucene is.

The documentation of [addDocuments()](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addDocuments%28java.lang.Iterable%29) states the following:

> Atomically adds a block of documents with sequentially assigned
>   document IDs, such that an external reader will see all or none of the
>   documents.
>
> **WARNING**: the index does not currently record which documents were added as a block. Today this is fine, because merging will preserve a
>   block. The order of documents within a segment will be preserved, even
>   when child documents within a block are deleted. Most search features
>   (like result grouping and block joining) require you to mark
>   documents; when these documents are deleted these search features will
>   not work as expected. Obviously adding documents to an existing block
>   will require you the reindex the entire block.

It doesn't sound like a block is a data structure, it's just a bunch of documents which are added in one commit.

But if that is true, how is the block preserved when merging?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be preserved since lucene guarantees to put these docs in the same segment and those are preserved across merges

Comment: Depending on the MergePolicy your segments are merged as well. And AFAIK default is to merge segments. So I can't see how that answers my question.